# Matlab GUI edit text to double

Tags: matlab, user-interface

Can anybody tell me what's wrong with that code?

```
c = str2double(get(handles.edit6,'String'));
```

Or how else can I get the edit input to be the value of c?

The command window shows: `'Warning: Infinite or Not-a-Number value encountered. ' 
(input of edit6 is '0')`

Code of the hole function:

```
function pushbutton1_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
kpr = get(handles.slider1,'Value');
kir = get(handles.slider2,'Value');
kdr = get(handles.slider3,'Value');
e = handles.e;
a = 0;
b = 0;
c = str2double(get(handles.edit6,'Value'));
for t = handles.time;
    ealt = e;
    if t<handles.sprung
        e = 0;
    else 
        e = (a*t^2)+(b*t)+ c;
    end
    B(1,handles.ix) = e;
    dedt = (e -ealt)/handles.h;
    y = e*kpr + kir*(integral(@(x) 0*x+e,0,t-handles.sprung)) + kdr*dedt; 
    A(1,handles.ix) = y;
    handles.ix = handles.ix+1;  
    hold on
    plot(t,e)
end
handles.A = A;
plot(handles.time,handles.A,'r')
```

Comment: Can you just show what `get(handles.edit6,'String')` outputs and its class, `class(get(handles.edit6,'String'))`

Comment: There's nothing wrong with `c = str2double(get(handles.edit6,'String'));`, as long as `handles.edit6` refers to a handle of a `uicontrol`. Can you provide some more code, tell which version of Matlab you are using and add some more details regarding the warining?

Comment: I'm using Version R2014a
The output of (get(handles.edit9,'Value')) is always 0. The output for str2double(get(handles.edit9,'Value')) = NaN

Comment: In the code you posted, you used `str2double(get(handles.edit6,'Value'))` instead of `str2double(get(handles.edit6,'String'))`.

Comment: oh sorry I just wanted to try it with 'Value'. but doesn't work as well